# Try to load two frame layout in main activity file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load two frame layouts for different activities. the problem is both the frames showing data at the same. I used setVisibilty method in the main java file. I want, when one frame is showing data the other frame hides automatically. Could anyone tell me the java codes.

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void setFrameVisibility (boolean frameOneVisible){
    if (frameOneVisible){
        findViewById(R.id.content_frame).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.content_frametwo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.content_frame).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.content_frametwo).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.homepage) {
        Intent homepage = new Intent (MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(homepage);
                        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.foodpage) {
        //handle the food page here
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new FirstFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.schedulepage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                , new ScheduleFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.emotionspage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                , new EmotionsFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.basicneedspage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frametwo
                , new BasicneedsFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.exit) {
        askBeforeExit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void onBackPressed() {

    askBeforeExit();
}

private void askBeforeExit(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Confirm Exit");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

Comment: you have not call the method yet on **onCreate**

Comment: Ok. can you please tell me or edit the codes for me. what is the right method

Comment: Just call the method...

Comment: Also, it's not clear why you have two FrameLayouts, but if you are trying to show different data, you should use Fragments instead and replace them within a single FrameLayout

Comment: How. can you please edit it for me bcoz i am little new in android.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, are you also new to Java? Because this isn't an Android problem. You wrote the `setFrameVisibility` method with a boolean parameter, yes? You need to actually call that method; just writing it doesn't execute the code within it

Comment: i want to show some data in the home page of my app and want another frame layout for rest of the options/buttons.

Comment: at which point you want to change the functionality of visibility. Means on which action perform

Comment: If you can see the onNavigationItemSelected, there i am trying to use two frame layouts, one is content_frame and another is content_frametwo.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method call to the `setFrameVisibility` in your `onCreate` and other methods that you want to do the toggling between two layouts:

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    setFrameVisibility(true); //or false
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i will be grateful, if you can edit it for me.

Comment: @ParveenPrajapati check your code, however you cannot see the edited text until peer review so just follow the solution here and add a single line back to your code

Comment: sorry to say you. i tried your method, but its not working.